# Firefox Extensions: Distinguish Navigation vs Resources

Tags: firefox, https

I'm trying to copy the mixed content feature of chrome into firefox. What I've got so far is to block all non-https requests on a site that is https. The problem is that navigation is treated the same as resources. Specifically, once on an https website, I can't navigate away from the site because the non-http request to navigate away is being rejected due to my code.

How do I see the difference between navigation and resource requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find an answer specifically to my question, but through other roots my friend was able to get the same solution. Resources that were useful follow:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy
2:40 AM 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICategoryManager
2:41 AM 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#Content_Policy